# My ReactJs Website does not open in Apple browser

Tags: ios, reactjs, browser, browserslist

I have a website created in react js, when I try to open it on windows or android the loading happens normally. But on IOS devices it doesn't load anything from the site.

I tried to change my "browserslist" in my **package.json** but I still couldn't. PS: I don't have a mac to debug, tests only on an iphone, I didn't find the iphone ios console to see the errors.

```
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
      "> 0.3%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
```

I also added recently a new dev dependencie on purpose to fix babel compilation issue

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11"
  }
}
```